# Automate environment preparation for password less ssh

Tags: linux

I am trying to achieve infrastructure as code. In this I am stuck with remote deployment. Remote deployment is possible when I manually copy public key to remote server s. I want this step to be automated as well. My script should paste public key to remote servers without prompting for password.Is there any way for automating this? If I am going with password less ssh then I should manually paste my public keys in all remote servers.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Several; if there is a password you could use `expect` or similar to automate the sending of the password part (there are many questions about this on this site) and other alternatives would be to build a particular key into the deployment image or otherwise install one via KickStart or similar such that a key is available to use following the deployment or install of the base OS image.

Comment: Do you have some links or docs? I tried googling but every time I got password less ssh.

Comment: Could you help me here??